# Issues with PHP and Mysql returning blank page

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple Form I am trying to code to get a handle on recoding a php page from drupal to linux. I Don't think I have access to all the old code, but doing my best. 
Here is the HTML code:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" action="keyset_checkin.php">
<div>
 <label for="edit-keysetnumber">Serial Number: </label>
 <input type="text" maxlength="128" name="keysetnumber"  size="60" value="" />
</div>
<input type="submit" name="op" value="Check In Keyset"  />
</form>
```

And then here is the PHP:

```
<?php

$dbhost = '*********';
$dbuser = '*********';
$dbpass = '*********';
$dbname = '*********';

$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
mysql_select_db($dbname);

/*$content .=  backLink();
    $content .= "<table border='0'><tr><td colspan='3'><strong>Keylog Report: All Keyset/Keys</strong></td></tr>";

    $content .= "</table>";
        return $content;
*/
        $content .= "<table border='0'><tr><td colspan='3'><strong>Keylog Report: All Keyset/Keys</strong></td></tr>";

    $query = "SELECT keysetnumber,keyring_id,building FROM {keyinv_key_sets} WHERE building NOT LIKE '%ZONE%' and building NOT LIKE '%SUPV%' GROUP BY keyring_id ORDER BY building ASC";

    $result = db_query($query);

    if(db_affected_rows() !=0)
    {   
        while($row = db_fetch_object($result))
        {
            $content .= "<tr><td valign='top'><font size='-3'><strong>$row->building</strong></font></td><td valign='top' width='50' align='center'><font size='-3'><strong>$row->keyring_id</strong></font></td>";

            $content .= "<td valign='top'>";

            //drupal_set_message($row->keysetnumber);   

            $query2 = "SELECT keytext, keydescription FROM {keyinv_keyset_keys} WHERE keysetnumber='$row->keysetnumber'";
            $result2 = db_query($query2);

            //drupal_set_message("Made it here");

            while($row2 = db_fetch_object($result2))
            {
                //drupal_set_message("Got Here");
                $content .= "<font size='-3'>$row2->keytext <font color='#CCCCCC'>($row2->keydescription)</font><font> ";
            }   

            $content .= "</td></tr>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $content .= "<tr><td>No Results</td></tr>";
    }

    $content .= "</table>";


        return $content;
?>
```

I've tried cutting it down to just the lines of

```
$content .= "<table border='0'><tr><td colspan='3'><strong>Keylog Report: All Keyset/Keys</strong></td></tr>";
$content .= "<tr><td>No Results</td></tr>";
$content .= "</table>";
```

And it just returns a blank page, where I thought at least those 3 lines would return an empty table with a header. I thought it was supposed to return in the page I was at, the table in the place of the form. What am I doing wrong here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to echo the result ($content) and not return it.

Comment: This fixed the problem of nothing being returned, However now trying to figure out how to return that data to the same page in a table, but thats another issue, you've gotten me a step forward.

Comment: The best thing to do would be to either create an isset() if conditional with the name $_POST['keysetnumber'] on the same page as your form, this will only display the result if the form has been submitted. Alternatively you can use ajax or just normal javascript post request to get the results to the page once the form has been submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like error reporting is not enabled.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

You can enable it either in code with the lines above or globally in php.ini

Comment: Thanks that should help a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
$content = "<table border='0'><tr><td colspan='3'><strong>Keylog Report: All Keyset/Keys</strong></td></tr>";

//rest of the code

echo $content;
```